# Datepicker issue

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am using date-picker in which we have multiple calendars, but problem is that while clicking on date field the calendars are shown in the background. please have a look at the link:

'http://builderfunding.co.in/doylesweb/index.html'

The code which we are using is shown below -

`

```
<div class="form-group input-group col-lg-4"> 
            <!-- <label for="exampleInputName2">When do you want to go?</label>--> 
            <!-- <input type="date" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2">-->
            <input id="datepicker" type="text" class="form-control">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span></span> </div>
              <div class="form-group input-group col-lg-4"> 
            <!-- <label for="exampleInputName2">When do you want to go?</label>--> 
            <!-- <input type="date" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2">-->
            <input id="datepicker1" type="text" class="form-control">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span></span> </div>
```

`

Comment: Your datepicker's z-index is 3, changing it to 10 brings it upfront.

Comment: yes like Radostin said try to use z-index:

Comment: Here is a working sample http://jsfiddle.net/BjtNY/1715/, try to clean your css for the datepickers and use the default one, then you can start from there..

Comment: yeah its working friends. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write this in your CSS file

```
.ui-datepicker {
  z-index: 10!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's Z index Issue

Just increase Z-index of your datepicker input

```
<input id="datepicker1" type="text" class="form-control" style="z-index: 20">
```

I have given inline styles. Instead of that please use a css